# Custom Marshaler for JSON that can be string or a map[string]string / map[string]bool

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I am working with a JSON response that can sometimes return a string or an object with string keys but values that are string and bool. I understand I need to implement my own Unmarshaler for the data

Example JSON Situations:

```
caseOne := `"data": [
    {"user": "usersName"}
]`

caseTwo := `"data": [
    {"user": {"id": "usersId", "isActive": true}}
]`
```

My Code:

```
package main

type Result struct {
    Data []Item `json:"data"`
}

type Item struct {
    User User `json:"user"`
}

type User struct {
    user string
}

func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(u.user)
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var raw interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(data, &raw)

    switch raw := raw.(type) {
    case string:
        *u = User{raw}
    case map[string]interface{}:
        // how do I handle the other "isActive" key that is map[string]bool?
        *u = User{raw["id"].(string)}
    }
    return nil

}
```

This question/answer: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305425/json-key-can-either-be-a-string-or-an-object) comes close to answering my use case but I am a bit stuck on how to handle multiple map values of different value types.

Current Go Playground:
[Here](https://go.dev/play/p/lNMMzZeADxf)

Comment: Use type `any` to represent different map value types: `map[string]any`.   Alternatively, define struct type with appropriate fields: `struct { ID string \`json:"id"\`; IsActive bool \`json:"isActive"\` }`

Comment: @CeriseLimón I'm not quite sure I follow how to take that into my example. I understand what you are stating, but how it ties into this I'm not quite sure I can piece it together.

Here is my current playground: https://go.dev/play/p/7HfuEAAUdu5

Comment: @CeriseLimón I've updated my playground to retrieve somewhat close of a result and added it to my question.

Comment: mkopriva's answer shows how to piece it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
type User struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    IsActive bool   `json:"isActive"`
}

func (u User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if u == (User{Name: u.Name}) { // check if u contains only name
        return json.Marshal(u.Name)
    }
    type U User
    return json.Marshal(U(u))
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    switch data[0] {
    case '"': // string?
        return json.Unmarshal(data, &u.Name)
    case '{': // object?
        type U User
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*U)(u))
    }

    return fmt.Errorf("unsupported JSON: %s", string(data))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/toOIz0XOQUo

---

If you pass `u` directly to `json.Marshal` from inside `MarshalJSON`, or if you pass it directly to `json.Unmarshal` from inside `UnmarshalJSON`, your program will get stuck in infinite recursion and eventually overflow the stack since `MarshalJSON/UnmarshalJSON` are called automatically by `json.Marshal/json.Unmarshal` on any value that implements those methods.

Type `U` is used to avoid this problem.

The statement `type U User` declares a new type `U` with its underlying type identical to that of `User`. Because the underlying types are identical we can easily convert one type to the other and back. However, the type declaration statement does not "carry over" the methods from the old type to the new type, so the new type `U` has none of the methods previously declared on `User` and therefore `json.Marshal/json.Unmarshal` will not get stuck in infinite call recursion anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this great write-up. Would the technique of creating a new Type be considered "type shadowing" or something else? Want to make sure I understand what this pattern is considered.

Comment: @Coldchain9 I'm afraid I don't know whether or not the pattern has a name.